# How to create an element

Tags: java, swing, frontend

I want to create this element in swing:
[image: An element]

As you can see the element is a small grid of buttons which appears when i click on another button. I've tried to use `JComboBox` to create this element. But as far as i know, `JComboBox` can just render an image of the some button, but it will not behave itself as a button. Also I couldn't set a `GridLayout` to `JComboBox`.

I also tried to create some `JDialog`, but I suppose that's bad idea.

So the question is: Which swing's component should I use to create mentioned element?

Comment: You can user an undecorated JDialog. You could try a JPopupMenu.

Comment: I've already used undecorated JDialog. The problem is that the main window is getting deactivated when I click the button which shows me my JDialog.

Comment: I will try JPopMenu. Thanks)

Comment: `The problem is that the main window is getting deactivated when I click the button which shows me my JDialog` - as it should, why is this a problem? When you click a button on the popup dialog, you would then close the popup and the main window will again have focus.

Answer (score 0):

You could use dialog in the best way to achieve this.

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog(owner);
dialog.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.MODELESS);
dialog.setUndecorated(true);
```

You could set Modality type to Modeless to avoid parent frame lock and set undecorated true to make jdialog without close option. But note that you need to close the dialog from program.